# Problem with mention detection discord bot javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to answer something when I mention it, it works once then the bot crashes and i get an error in this code:

```
bot.on('message', message =>{
    if(message.mentions.members.first().id == '602929944779292682'){
        message.channel.sendMessage('**A votre service!**')
    }
})
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the members element before getting its `id`

```
bot.on('message', message =>{
    if (message.mentions.members.first() !== undefined) {
        if(message.mentions.members.first().id == '602929944779292682'){
            message.channel.sendMessage('**A votre service!**')
        }
    } else {
        // Handle members.first() is undefined
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things in advance:

**1.** Use always `===`/`!==` and not `==`/`!=`!

**2.** `channel.sendMessage()` is deprecated! Use `channel.send()` instead.

---

Cleaned up code and problem fixed (much like @ThanhPhan does)

```
bot.on("message", message => {

 if (message.mentions.members.first() !== undefined) {

  if (message.mentions.members.first().id === bot.user.id) { # This is the bots user id

   message.channel.send("**A votre service!**")

  }

 }

})
```

Comment: Thanks but i did Something else:
`bot.on('message', async message =>{
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.mentions.members.size && message.mentions.members.first().id == '602929944779292682'){`

Comment: @MathDesigns Post an answer including that code so future readers know the solution that worked for you. See ["Can I answer my own question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).